# Oops! Downloaded a virus (win32-DOS)!

Tags: windows-7, virus

I'm on Windows 7 and accidentally downloaded a virus. It's not that bad, but it gives alerts that Windows has crashed. Nothing still happens.

> APPCRASH - Application: win32-DOS.exe.exe

That's the report, so I suggest that that file causes the problem. When I right-click it in Task Manager and click "File location", it takes me to folder (C:\Windows\System32\Win32-DOS) with two files: logs.dat and plugin.dat.

How can I delete this? I googled but didn't success in the only instructions I could found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, try using an antimalware program might get rid of it. Try the free version of [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), for instance.

You also might be able to delete the `Win32-DOS` folder from within Windows or from a Linux LiveCD ([Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.org/) is small), but if it was me I'd want to scan around with an antimalware program and make pretty sure that it was all gone even if I tried to get rid of it that way.

Comment: Malwarebytes worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Hitman Pro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/hitmanpro) to clean infected machines lately, it's really good for already-infected machines.

It scans in like 3-5 minutes, and uses 5 or 6 different AV engines to do it.

It's kind of a scan-for-free, pay-to-clean utility, but they currently give you a free 30 day cleaning trial.  Which is plenty fair and useful when you're already infected. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into safe mode (Make sure to select the "Administrator" account, not your own - I believe it should be visible in safe mode), navigate there, and hit the delete key ;)
You may also want to run some sort of antivirus while you're there.